# Scrolltop não funciona quando uso o elemento Body e sim HTML

Tags: jquery, css, html5

Eu não encontrei uma resposta e nem na documentação do jQuery. Pois quando uso elemento **"body"** para o animate com a propriedade scrollTop que quero animar não funciona.

Segue meu código

```
    function scrollPlacar() {
  $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".placar").offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

Porem quando eu faço dessa forma.

```
function scrollPlacar() {
  $('html').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".placar").offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

Funciona perfeitamente, mas ainda queria saber porque **html** e não o **body**?

Comment: coloque os outros códigos html para analisarmos por favor

Comment: Anderson o seu Body tinha altura? Certifique-se de que seu Body e o HTML tenham valores no `height`, tipo `html, body {height:100%}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por padrão, o `overflow` da página toda é do `html`. Se você ocultar o *overflow* do `html`, você pode ativar o scroll do `body`, mas é preciso também definir a altura do `body` e do `html` para 100% do *viewport* (área visível do documento na janela do navegador) e ativar o `overflow` do `body`.

Sem fazer todas essas *manobras*, o `body` não é rolável, e por isso o `animate` não consegue fazer a rolagem.

Veja um exemplo de `animate` com o `body` dentro das definições explicadas acima:

```js
function scrollPlacar() {
  $('body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".placar").offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
scrollPlacar();
```

```css
html{
   overflow: hidden;
}
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
body{
   overflow: auto;
   margin: 0;
}
.placar{
   background: red;
   height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Início do documento
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="placar">animar até aqui</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```